# column to row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have got a table let say table T1 and in the table there are names and I want to know the position of Greg and Ammy for a different time, Let say before 6:59 AM, between 7:00 AM to 11:59 PM and after 12:00 PM. But here is the catch, I want to create a query which shows latitude and longitude in column named as 6:59 AM, 7:00 AM - 11:59 PM, after 12:00 PM.

```
Table1:
-------------------------------------------------------
| Name |          Date        | Lattitude | Longitude |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Greg | 2017-05-20T00:05:12  |   24.55   |   60.56   |
| Greg | 2017-05-20T08:05:12  |   28.05   |   59.56   |   
| Greg | 2017-05-20T13:05:12  |   20.15   |   61.56   |
| Ammy | 2017-05-20T06:30:10  |   24.55   |   60.56   |
| Ammy | 2017-05-20T11:08:11  |   26.95   |   28.56   |
| Ammy | 2017-05-20T14:00:00  |   20.45   |   15.56   |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Google Oracle Pivot

Answer (score 0):

You need to first use a case statement to categorize each row into the 3 time periods you described, for example:

```
select name, lattitude, longitude,
case when date_tm < '20-MAY-17 07:00:00' then '6:59AM'
     when date_tm < '20-MAY-17 12:00:00' then '7:00AM - 11:59PM'
     else '12:00PM' end as time_period
from T1.
```

Then, you can pivot to change rows into columns:

```
select *
from
(select name, Lattitude||','|| Longitude  as lat_long,
 case when date_tm < '20-MAY-17 07:00:00' then '6:59AM'
     when date_tm < '20-MAY-17 12:00:00' then '7:00AM - 11:59PM'
     else '12:00PM' end as time_period
from T1)

PIVOT

(
    max(lat_long) for time_period in ('6:59AM','7:00AM - 11:59PM','12:00PM')
);
```